# Synonymize [pixel] and [pixels]

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

Could we synonymize the tags [pixel](/questions/tagged/pixel) and [pixels](/questions/tagged/pixels)?

[pixel](/questions/tagged/pixel) has 762 questions.

[pixels](/questions/tagged/pixels) has 329 questions.

Plural is supposed to win, so even though the singular form has more questions, I'd go with keeping the plural.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist No, see the tag wiki. it states clearly that it refers to the "usual" pixel.

Comment: @Theemath It was a joke.

Comment: @TheemathasChirananthavat - That was just a joke ("Pixel" Daisuke is the creator of Cave Story). Anyway, I agree with the proposal. Even the two tag wiki are almost identical.