# Formatting synonym requests to "meet the quality standards"

Tags: support, asking-questions, synonym-request, quality-filter

When suggesting a tag synonym (which doesn't need much explanation because they are obviously synonyms) how to format the question?
Note: I've asked a tag synonym request once, and I have problems to get it to "meet your quality standards". That will surely discourage many users from making synonym requests.

Comment: Really? I've never had any problems... your (edited) question looks quite good. I doubt you would have had any problems with the current version. What did you try and post?

Comment: [This is what I format it like](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166559/synonymize-pixel-and-pixels)

Comment: @Doorknob I would like you to post your comment as a answer so I can accept it as answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered in a comment by Doorknob (see above) but he/she didn't properly make an answer, so I'm posting it as an answer here:
[Synonymize [pixel] and [pixels]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166559/synonymize-pixel-and-pixels)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I never did do that :P Anyway, glad I helped!